# dynamically building a class reference in python

Tags: python, class

I have a csv file with headers and I am trying to use the headers to identify locations in a class for updating.

```
Age, all, bladder, brain, breast,...
0, 23.34, 0, 3.8905, 0, ...
1, 22.7339, 0, 4.4064, 0,...
```

I have a list "baseline" with 98 entries, and each entry includes a field .cancer, and in .cancer there are fields .all, .bladder, .brain, .breast and so on so that the prevalence of bladder cancer in 50 year olds can be accessed as

```
baseline[50].cancer.bladder.prevalence
```

I need a command that would do something like:

```
k=0
for row in csv_data:
    for j in range(len(row)):
        baseline[k].cancer.header[j].prevalence = row[j]
    k += 1
```

so that a part of the name (i.e. bladder, brain...) comes from the headers.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Try looking into pandas dataframes.

Comment: You can always get a subobject with `getattr(parentobject, "subobject_name")`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers.  Looks like I will need to implement something like brian's answer below in the short term before learning about pandas and rewriting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Though this looks like a job for `pandas`, it's possible to accomplish this if the column number/order is fixed. The following code should work: note that it leverages some Python 3 functionality:

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    _, *cancer_columns = next(data) # capture the headers

    for age, *cancers in data:
        for i, cancer in enumerate(cancers):
            # dynamically get attribute and assign based on cancer_columns index
            getattr(baseline[age].cancer, cancer_columns[i]).prevalence = float(cancer)
```